# Delete item from listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have listview which contains textview and buttons. When i delete listview item and i try to scroll down, i get exception on this:

```
BuildQueue eile = countryList.get(position);
```

Exception:

```
02-08 19:11:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10509): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
```

Seems i do not updating something when i delete item from listview. I think i have problem with ViewHolder, but i do not know what kind of...

My ArrayAdapter code:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BuildQueue> {

        private ArrayList<BuildQueue> countryList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<BuildQueue> countryList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
            this.countryList = new ArrayList<BuildQueue>();
            this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView code;
            TextView field;
            Button del;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.queue_buildings, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                holder.field = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.field_text);
                holder.del = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.del_button);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Button del_button = (Button) v;
                        BuildQueue building = (BuildQueue) del_button.getTag();
                        countryList.remove(building);
                        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            BuildQueue eile = countryList.get(position);
            holder.code.setText(" ( Level: " + eile.getOld_level() + " to "+eile.getNew_level()+")");

            holder.field.setText(eile.getNameSort());
            holder.field.setTag(eile);

            holder.del.setText("Delete");
            holder.del.setTag(eile);

            return convertView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You use `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: yes, dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a two arrays in your Adapter, but only changing one of them.

Every Adapter uses `getCount()` to determine how many row should be drawn. ArrayAdapter's [`getCount()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getCount%28%29) simply asks for the size of the array that you pass to the super constructor here: `super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);`.  But you are also using a second, local array and when you delete a value from this `countryList` `getCount()` has no idea this happened which results in `getView()` throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException...

Either extend BaseAdapter, or use ArrrayAdapter's methods like [`getItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29), [`add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29), and [`remove()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) and remove your local data set.

Comment: i've added:
dataAdapter.remove(building);
now it works, thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help. (If you haven't done so, I highly recommend removing the local copy of `countryList` to prevent any future errors like this.)